# navigating to spring security login page redirects to invalid-session-url

Tags: spring-security

In order to redirect the user to a url that I desire on session timeout I recently added the following to my spring security file....

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/resources/js/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/resources/css/**" security="none"/>
<!-- excluded pages -->
<http pattern="/login.htm" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/j_spring_security_check" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/accessDenied.htm" security="none"/> 
<http pattern="/error.htm" security="none"/>

<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">    
    <!-- custom filters -->
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="twoFactorAuthenticationFilter" />      
    <custom-filter after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="securityLoggingFilter"/>
    <!-- session management -->     
    <session-management 
        invalid-session-url="/sessionExpired.htm" 
        session-authentication-error-url="/alreadyLoggedIn.htm">

        <concurrency-control 
            max-sessions="1" 
            expired-url="/sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin.htm" 
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" 
            session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>

    </session-management>
```

When the session expires on the next click the user is taken to /sessionExpired.htm which is the desired effect HOWEVER i now have an issue when I navigate to the login page (login.htm), i am redirected to invalid-session-url (/sessionExpired.htm).

Obviously this is not what I want to happen. I've been doing some reading on it and one of the suggested solutions seems to be to delete the jsessionid cookie like such and also set invalidate-session to false (I now invalidate session in the controller method for logout.htm) ...

```
<logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" invalidate-session="false" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
```

which I have tried but doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help me understand what is happening here and how I might resolve? It seems as if when i go to the login page it is trying to remember who I am.

thanks

Comment: can you post code where you have mapped url with roles required.
I guess you have marked login url with some required role. On login page you should give permitAll expression. If you could not figure out this then send the code for url mapping with security manger.

Comment: I've edited to show I am using none for the login page

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem in Tomcat (not sure if only applies to it).

From Tomcat documentation ([see here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)) we can conclude that the path generated for the session cookie has a trailing slash:

> Some browsers, such as IE, will send a session cookie for a context with a path of /foo with a request to /foobar. To prevent this, Tomcat will add a trailing slash to the path associated with the session cookie so, in the above example, the cookie path becomes /foo/. However, with a cookie path of /foo/, IE will no longer send the cookie with a request to /foo. This should not be a problem unless there is a servlet mapped to /*. In this case this feature will need to be disabled. The default value for this attribute is true. To disable this feature, set the attribute to false.

On the other side, spring-security's [CookieClearingLogoutHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/CookieClearingLogoutHandler.java) will generate a cookie path without the trailing slash. The set-cookie response header will be sent to the browser, but the cookie path will not match the path because the trailing slash is missing.

The browser will not clear the existing JSESSIONID cookie because the paths do not match.

I solved my problem implementing a custom implementation of the CookieClearingLogoutHandler.

Comment: wow that is a great answer. I'm going to try and do this as well. Would you mind posting a snippet of the custom cookieclearinglogouthandler for me to get an idea of what you did?

Comment: public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", null);
        cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath() + "/");
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }

Comment: This has been fixed in Spring Security 5.0 and 4.2: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2325