# spring security set cookie to null not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, setcookie

i am setting cookie `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE` to null when user logs out.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, null);
String cookiePath = request.getContextPath();
cookie.setPath(cookiePath);
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

above code working fine in my localhost, when i moved to cloud server, the above code doesn't works, it is not removing the cookie while logging off. there is no difference other than domain forwarding.

Comment: Try to invalidate the session on logout `<security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/myapp/auth/login" logout-url="/myapp/auth/logout" />`

Comment: session is getting invalidated, but the problem is, the remember me functionality which is loggin in again. user log-off takes to login page, to avoid autologin, i am removing remember me cookie which is not working here

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be your case, but there is a similar issue regarding the removal of JSESSIONID cookies. Take a look here:

- [Spring Security - Session Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-mgmt)
- [navigating to spring security login page redirects to invalid-session-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423039/navigating-to-spring-security-login-page-redirects-to-invalid-session-url)

The same thing may be happening to the Remember-Me cookie. Check the 'Set-Cookie' headers when you log out of your system (Firebug is enough for this): if the 'path' does not match the path for the stored cookie (created when accessing the login page), then you may have this issue on your environment. In this case, you could create a custom `CookieClearingLogoutHandler` to properly clean the cookies.